# How to fill specific SelectField with the data returned from ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, flask-wtforms

**Update later...** I finally get my problem solved. I just wonder if there is a way doing this **more** **elegant**?

I'm at the very beginning of programing with `Python3`, `Flask` and `Jquery`.

What I aim to do is that making one `SelectField` change its value(s) based on another `SelectField`'s option.  Just like, when I choose US as country, then automatically load states(say, New York/Washington, D.C./...) from database with ajax help.

Now I could get data using ajax call, which means I could see the response in debug mode of Browser. I just do not know how to fill the specific `SelectField` with the response data. Below is the relevant code snippet. Thanks in advance for your time.

**choose.html**

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
...
<div class="row">
  <form action="{{url_for('some_view_function')}}" method="post">
    ...
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      {{ form.country(class="form-control select2_single") }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      {{ form.state(class="form-control select2_single") }}
    </div>
    ...
  </form>
</div>
...
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#country").change(function(){
          country_id=$("#country").val();
          $.get("{{ url_for('get_states_by_country') }}",
                {"country_id":country_id},
                function(data, status){
                    if (status == 'success') {
                        // What should I do here with data?
                    }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**view_function.py**

```
@app.route('/obtain/states', methods={'GET', 'POST'})
def get_states_by_country():
    country_id = request.args.get("country_id")

    states = State.query.filter_by(
        country_id=country_id
    )
    return jsonify(
        {int(s.state_id): s.state_name
         for s in states}
    )
```

**form.py**

```
class LinkChooseForm(Form):
    country = SelectField(label='Country')
    state = SelectField(label='State')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.country.choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in Country.query.all()]
        self.state.choices = [] # I leave it empty when initiating
```

**Update-1:**
The data is `json` format. Mock data below. The `key` would be `value` of `<option>`, and `value` would be `text` of `<option>`.

```
{
  "bash", "desc_for_bash",
  "csh", "desc_for_csh",
  ...
}
```

**Update-2:**
With @Deepak's help, I finally solved this problem. The issue I mentioned under @Deepak's answer(form doesn't accept select option) is post wrong. In fact, `form` does accept the select option on my `html` page. I debug that and find out I miss to reset `state.choices` in my action function. You could notice that I leave the `state.choices` empty when initiating form object. But `flask-wtf` would validate that if your choice on page is one of `state.choices`. Which is obviously not, since I leave it empty. So I must reset it with `request.form.get('state')` to meet `flask-wtf`'s validation. Below is submit function.

```
@app.route('/test', methods={'GET', 'POST'})
def some_view_function():
    form = LinkChooseForm(**request.view_args)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # The most important part here.
        form.state.choices = [(request.form.get('state'), "")]

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            action_entity = ActionEntity()
            action_entity.do(form)
            return redirect(url_for('.another_view_function'))
        else:
            # reset it as empty again
            form.state.choices = []

    return render_template(
        'result.html',
        form=form
    )
```

Comment: why cant you use plugins for that.why are you dumping the db

Comment: https://www.cssscript.com/demo/generic-country-state-dropdown-list-countries-js/ please refer this.hope this helps

Comment: @Deepak Thanks for your time. But  what I put up here is just an example. In fact, I have two `SelectFields` with specific business meaning, not `country` and `state`.

Comment: can you post your json data or a mock json so that i can write the code

Comment: @Deepak I edited my post, is that enough? Thanks.

Comment: i have posted the code,pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = '{"bash":"desc_for_bash","csh":"desc_for_csh, city"}';//Your JSON data
data = JSON.parse(data);                                        //To parse your JSON data
var str=''
for(d in data)
str+='<option value="'+d+'">'+data[d]+'</option>'

$("#your_select_id").html(str)                                 //For adding options to select
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me. Only an issue, but it's my fault. According to my code in `view_function.py`, you could see the data is already `json` object. So I just remove the `data=Json.parse(data);` part. You may put up some description for your answer.

Comment: But it still blocks me when submitting the whole form. Seems like the page doesn't accept any option for this `SelectField`. Maybe you could help further. Thanks again.

Comment: are you telling that the form does'nt accept SelectField value on submit?

Comment: Thank u Deepak, it turns out my code's wrong, not "form doesn't accept SelectFeild value on submit". I've already solved that. I just wonder: is there a way doing this more elegant? I mean on javascript part mainly. I just do not want to makeup `html` code in `<script>`.